# I need this script to rerun when the window is resized, as well as on page load

Tags: javascript, responsive

I need this script to rerun when the window is resized, as well as on page load.
if the script waits a half of a second before it loads, i would like to see that code too.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('gdlr-item');

var elementHeights = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(el)  {
  return el.clientHeight;
});

var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, elementHeights);

// surround this in a function

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
el.style.height = maxHeight + "px"
});

// Call the function a half second after the page loads
// Call the function when the window resizes
```

Comment: Watch for the window `resize` and `load` events.  Make sure you debounce resize handling, because it fires continuously while the user resizes the window.

Comment: Put the code in a named function. Then call it in the `resize` and `load` event handlers.